# cursor JAVASCRIPT needs to be adapted to wordpress DOCTYPE

Tags: javascript, cursor, doctype

if you are experienced with relations between javascript and doctype declaration , any help would be appreciated. i use wordpress and i am trying to include cursor script into a page. the script works without default wordpress doctype, with it - it does not. any suggestions how to make the cursor script work, please?

HTML doctype declaration for my WordPress:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Code for cursor:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
    <!--
    .kisser {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      visibility:hidden;
    }
    -->
    </STYLE>

    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/JavaScript">
    <!-- cloak

    //Kissing trail
    //Visit http://www.rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com for this script

    kisserCount = 15 //maximum number of images on screen at one time
    curKisser = 0 //the last image DIV to be displayed (used for timer)
    kissDelay = 1200 //duration images stay on screen (in milliseconds)
    kissSpacer = 30 //distance to move mouse b4 next heart appears
    theimage = "cur.png" //the 1st image to be displayed
    theimage2 = "small_heart.gif" //the 2nd image to be displayed



    //Browser checking and syntax variables
    var docLayers = (document.layers) ? true:false;
    var docId = (document.getElementById) ? true:false;
    var docAll = (document.all) ? true:false;
    var docbitK = (docLayers) ? "document.layers['":(docId) ? "document.getElementById('":(docAll) ? "document.all['":"document."
    var docbitendK = (docLayers) ? "']":(docId) ? "')":(docAll) ? "']":""
    var stylebitK = (docLayers) ? "":".style"
    var showbitK = (docLayers) ? "show":"visible"
    var hidebitK = (docLayers) ? "hide":"hidden"
    var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
    //Variables used in script
    var posX, posY, lastX, lastY, kisserCount, curKisser, kissDelay, kissSpacer, theimage
    lastX = 0
    lastY = 0
    //Collection of functions to get mouse position and place the images
    function doKisser(e) {

      posX = getMouseXPos(e)
      posY = getMouseYPos(e)
      if (posX>(lastX+kissSpacer)||posX<(lastX-kissSpacer)||posY>(lastY+kissSpacer)||posY<(lastY-kissSpacer)) {
        showKisser(posX,posY)
        lastX = posX
        lastY = posY
      }
    }
    // Get the horizontal position of the mouse
    function getMouseXPos(e) {
      if (document.layers||ns6) {
        return parseInt(e.pageX+10)
      } else {
        return (parseInt(event.clientX+10) + parseInt(document.body.scrollLeft))
      }
    }
    // Get the vartical position of the mouse
    function getMouseYPos(e) {
      if (document.layers||ns6) {
        return parseInt(e.pageY)
      } else {
        return (parseInt(event.clientY) + parseInt(document.body.scrollTop))
      }
    }
    //Place the image and start timer so that it disappears after a period of time
    function showKisser(x,y) {
      var processedx=ns6? Math.min(x,window.innerWidth-75) : docAll? Math.min(x,document.body.clientWidth-55) : x
      if (curKisser >= kisserCount) {curKisser = 0}
      eval(docbitK + "kisser" + curKisser + docbitendK + stylebitK + ".left = " + processedx)
      eval(docbitK + "kisser" + curKisser + docbitendK + stylebitK + ".top = " + y)
      eval(docbitK + "kisser" + curKisser + docbitendK + stylebitK + ".visibility = '" + showbitK + "'")
      if (eval("typeof(kissDelay" + curKisser + ")")=="number") {
        eval("clearTimeout(kissDelay" + curKisser + ")")
      }
      eval("kissDelay" + curKisser + " = setTimeout('hideKisser(" + curKisser + ")',kissDelay)")
      curKisser += 1
    }
    //Make the image disappear
    function hideKisser(knum) {
      eval(docbitK + "kisser" + knum + docbitendK + stylebitK + ".visibility = '" + hidebitK + "'")
    }

    function kissbegin(){
    //Let the browser know when the mouse moves
    if (docLayers) {
      document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
      document.onMouseMove = doKisser
    } else {
      document.onmousemove = doKisser
    }
    }
    window.onload=kissbegin
    // decloak -->
    </SCRIPT>


    <!--Simply copy and paste just before </BODY> section of your page.-->

    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    <!-- cloak
    // Add all DIV's of hearts
    if (document.all||document.getElementById||document.layers){
    for (k=0;k<kisserCount;k=k+2) {
      document.write('<div id="kisser' + k + '" class="kisser"><img src="' + theimage + '" alt="" border="0"></div>\n')
      document.write('<div id="kisser' + (k+1) + '" class="kisser"><img src="' + theimage2 + '" alt="" border="0"></div>\n')

    }
    }

    // decloak -->
    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Testing for 4.x era browsers? Using a big stack of globals? Making extensive use of `eval`? Hogging `onload`? This script is full of work arounds for ancient browsers and terrible, terrible style. I'd throw it out and start from scratch (well, not quite, since it is a cursor trail script, I'd just throw it out and then go away to shudder for a while).

Comment: That script is pretty horrible.  What do you really want to achieve?  Grabbing nasty old scripts from highly questionable sources like that is not the best way to get a modern website working.

Answer (score 0):

The script is riddled with very old browser detection code, this could cause it to break in 'newer' browsers with a stricter DOCTYPE.

Try to remove the 'language="JavaScript1.2"' in the script tag. If that doesn't work you'd have to rewrite the browser detection.

The actual script isn't very complicated though so perhaps you could find parts elsewhere and combine them.
You need to do two things:

1. Hide the cursor (which is done with CSS)
2. Fetch the mouse position and place your own cursor there (typically an image). For this you will need a script that fetch the mouse position.

Shouldn't be too hard :)

Comment: The `language` attribute doesn't do anything, it is deprecated and only used as a last resort for browsers to determine the type of the script (if it doesn't assume JavaScript to be the default (very rare, nowadays) and there's no `type` attribute); you can't change the behaviour of the JavaScript engine using that old, deprecated attribute. Moreover, in modern browsers you can style the cursor image using CSS; not that I like it, but it's possible.

Comment: language is deprecated and type is most certainly required (check W3C).

Comment: Not in the [latest spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#script), where it was defaulted to `text/javascript` because all browsers assumed that type when it wasn't specified.